# How can I create leave approval In sharepoint-2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm new to SharePoint and I'd like to Create a Leave approval Form Application which utilizes the Approval Workflow, Approver  as  userprofile  feild  in  sharepoint-2010?. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

http://workflowvalidation.codeplex.com/

you can using this solution, to create a custom validation process.
In your case, you create a Leave List (Creator, start date, final date...), you associate the workflow (Validation Workflow) to this list. And you create your custom process, the validator can defined in the column list or in the user profile service.
example: The Manager of the author.

if you have any problem contact me.